# How can I share the ViewModel between multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

This is my SessionViewModel Factory

```
class SessionViewModelFactory(
    private val sessionId: String
) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SessionViewModel::class.java)) {
            SessionViewModel(
                sessionId = sessionId,
                sessionRepository = SessionRepository(
                    WebserviceGenerator.webservice,
                    AppDatabase.getDatabase()?.questionDao()
                )
            ) as T
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("ViewModel Not Found")
        }
    }
}
```

I want SessionViewModel to be shared among all the fragments having the same sessionId.

Example:
Lets assume we have fragments as following
Fragment #1 has sessionId "a".
Fragment #2 has sessionId "a".
Fragment #3 has sessionId "b".
Fragment #4 has sessionId "b".

Then,
Fragment #1 and Fragment #2 should have the same instance of SessionViewModel.
Fragment #3 and Fragment #4 should have the same instance of SessionViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, viewmodel exists while you app is running. 
The good thing is: it is not killed when your activity / fragments is killed.

You can call the same viewmodel from differents fragments.

Let's say you have

```
var myQuantity
```

inside your view model.

From fragm A you can call the viewmodel and set myQuantity value to 5, for example.
Then from fragm B you can call the viewmodel and get myQuantity value, you'll get 5

You cant find more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) (how to call the viewmodel,...)